# Proving multi variable function bijective

Tags: functions

Assume $f:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ and f is defined as $f((x,y))=(x+y,x-y)$
How do I prove $f$ is bijective? I am new into this category and I understand how to prove a simple single variable function. But when it comes to the above question I am confused.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I mistyped. It is $f((x,y))= (x+y, x-y)$

Comment: The function is linear, so it suffices to even just check basis elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injectivity:

Suppose $f(x,y)=f(a,b)$. Then $(x+y,x-y)=(a+b,a-b)$. Doing some re-arranging and substitution, one finds
$$a=x+b-y \implies x+y=x+b-y+b \implies 2y=2b \implies y=b \implies a=x  $$
So $(x,y)=(a,b)$, thus $f$ is injective.

Surjectivity:

Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be arbitrary, and we'll seek some $(x,y): f(x,y)=(a,b)$. Note that setting $(x,y) = (\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a-b}{2})$ yields:
$$f(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a-b}{2}) = (\frac{a+b+a-b}{2}, \frac{a+b-a+b}{2})=(a,b)$$

A couple of notes: I didn't just guess that we should set $x:=\frac{a+b}{2}$ -- this can actually be deduced by manipulating the equations given from $f(x,y) = (x+y,x-y)=(a,b)$. I'd encourage you to give it a try!

Also, if you find yourself not just working with $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you're asked to prove that some function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjection (onto) then keep in mind that what you really need to show is that for anything in $Y$, there's some $x$ in $X$ so that $f(x)=y$ (i.e. $f$ hits all the elements of $Y$). For injectivity (one-to-one), you'll (generally) want to assume that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and show that $x_1=x_2$. The good news is that depending on what $f, X,$ and $Y$ look like there may be shortcuts to showing these properties.

Answer (score 0):

Given $(z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ you need that $x+y=z$ and $x-y=w$, which leads to $2x= z+w$ and $2y=z-w$. This gives you a formula for $x$ and $y$ and thus, shows that $f$ is surjective.  To show that $f$ is injective : if $(x+y,x-y)=(z+w, z-w)$, then $x+y=z+w$ and $x-y=z-w$ from where you get $2x=2z$ and hence $z=x$. Similarly, $y=w$.